# Is there a way to use inline sass into Angular2 components?

Tags: angular, sass, webpack

I have an Angular 2 project based on a [Webpack starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter). I'm trying to figure out how to use SASS directly into components (without calling an external `.scss` file).
Every examples I found use `styleUrls` and the extension name `.scss` to recognize when to call the `sass-loader`.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Use the [`sass-loader`](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader): `require("!raw-loader!sass-loader!./file.scss")`; this returns compiled CSS code from `file.scss`, resolves SASS imports.</s>

When specifying `styles: '//SASS style'`, webpack has no way to determine that the style is in SASS and that the `sass-loader` should be used. You will need to use the following pattern:

```
import styles from './styles.sass';
@Component({
  styles: styles
})
```

Comment: I already use the sass-loader `{ test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['raw-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap'] }` combined with `styleUrls: ['./file.scss']` in my component but what I want is to be able to put directly scss code into it using `styles: ['...scss code...']`

Comment: Yes this is why I'm asking if there is a trick to call the sass-loader without using .scss files. The goal is to keep my TS, HTML and SCSS in the same file for little components.

Comment: @simon04 you mention there is no way for webpack to determine that the style is "SASS", but what about using SASS syntax "always"? Is there a way to configure this? AFAIK, SASS is CSS3-source compatible.

Comment: @Bernard - obvious, isn't it? :) To use SASS always